# Can I make text appear to be fixed while scrolling over fixed background images?

Tags: html, css

[Here is my fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/nhfyo6nv/2/)

I'm trying to create a web page where the user can scroll through multiple full-screen images that have overlayed HTML elements that appear to be fixed (not move on scroll).

In my fiddle, you can see that I currently have the text positioned absolute and they move relative to their parent. Instead, I would like to position the text where I would like it to appear over each background image, then when the user scrolls down, the text stays fixed and then is covered/uncovered by the next section (depending on direction).

I did try to use `position: fixed` and z-index values but I could always see the fixed elements when I'd like the fixed elements to only be visible with its own slide.

Adding text with the image files does not meet my requirements as ultimately I'd like dynamic text and video elements to be in these fixed elements. Much thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this using pure css. Please see this snippet.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("section .cover-text").each(function() {
    var marginTop = $(window).scrollTop() - $(this).parent().position().top;
    $(this).css({
      'margin-top': marginTop
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#slide-1,
#slide-2,
#slide-3 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cover-1,
.cover-2,
.cover-3 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cover-1 {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/350');
  z-index: 3000;
}

.cover-2 {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/800/350');
}

.cover-3 {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/355');
}

.cover-text {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 30px #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="slide-1">
  <div class="cover-1"></div>
  <div class="cover-text">Title 1</div>
</section>
<section id="slide-2">
  <div class="cover-2"></div>
  <div class="cover-text">Title 2</div>
</section>
<section id="slide-3">
  <div class="cover-3"></div>
  <div class="cover-text">Title 3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Kumar Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Update: This works great in most browsers. But I did notice that in the latest version of Safari on Mac the text is very jumpy as you scroll. In other browsers it looks very smooth.

Comment: @Davyd: Try addinf the vendor prefix for transform. See my updated snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JinuKurian - I tried the vendor prefixes and I still see the overlayed text bounce a bit on scroll. I also tried to remove the transform property completely but I was still able to see the text move on scroll in Safari.

Comment: @Davyd Spot the issue. Let me check.